# JSFにおいて、action付ボタン押下後に発生するエラー

Tags: java, xhtml, jsf

JSFで、以下のようなaction付ボタンをxhtmlで実装しました。

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <title>Sample</title>
</h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h2>test</h2>
        <h:form>
            <h:commandButton value="読込み" action="#{personalInformationStatefulBean.load()}"/>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

このプログラムを実行し、「読込み」と表示されているボタンを押下して、
PersonalInformationStatefulBeanクラスのloadメソッドを呼びたいのですが、
実際の所、6割ぐらいの確率で以下のようなstackTraceが出力されてしまいます。

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to locate a business interface declaring public void BusinessLogic.PersonalInformationStatefulBean.load()
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)
io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166)
io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197)
io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

ただ、4割ぐらいの確率で正常に実行できる場合もあるので、頭を悩ませている状況です。
どのような原因が考えられるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

Viewの定義自体は問題がないようにみえます。PersonalInformationStatefulBeanはどのような定義となっていますでしょうか？名前だけからの推測ですが、EJBを直接呼出ししているようにみえます。

CDI管理Bean(@Named)を利用されていますでしょうか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
PersonalInformationStatefulBeanの定義ですが、おっしゃられた通り、@Stateful,@Named,
@LocalBean,@RequestScopedをつけたEJBのクラスとして作成しています。また、実装としてSerializableインターフェースを使用しています。